# Bind DNS for wildcard subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm on a Windows 7 VM with Apache. I'm trying to get Bind DNS setup to route subdomains to the same place as the main domain. The main domain routes correctly to 172.16.5.1 as specified in the hosts file. But the subdomains are still routing to the 127.0.0.1

I haven't added anything to the httpd.conf because I don't *think I need to. Here are my bind files. Any ideas of what might be wrong? I'm also not sure what 'hostmaster' should be changed to, if anything, in the zone file.

/etc/named file:

```
options {
    directory "c:\named\zones";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    recursion no;
};


zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "db.eg.com.txt";
};

#allow-transfer { none; };

# Use with the following in named.conf, adjusting the allow list as needed:
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "Rha8Z8AKxOeg+asqZQ==";
};

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
```

zones/db.eg.com.txt file:

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN SOA  eg.com. hostmaster.eg.com. (
            2011100911
            10800
            3600
            604800
            86400 )

@       NS  eg.com.
*   IN A    172.16.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete Working Wildcard-zone (Live from my DNS) could look like

```
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     ns400.domain.it. ns-admin.domain.it. (
                        2020051801      ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

                                      IN NS   ns400.domain.it.
                                      IN NS   ns401.domain.it.
                                      IN NS   ns402.domain.it.
*.domain.it.                          IN A    10.0.0.1
domain.it.                            IN A    10.0.0.1
ns400.domain.it                       IN A    10.0.0.2
ns401.domain.it                       IN A    10.0.0.3
ns402.domain.it                       IN A    10.0.0.4
$ORIGIN @
```

It may not be the best used and advised Solution, but it's doing the Job :-)
However, you usually would need 2 Domain Servers, if its LAN-Only you can reduce it to one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an NS. Then it should work. an A record for the NS is what I meant. Nevermind I just read what you put down, you can't be your own ns at least not initially. and you are missing several ";".

http://pastebin.com/JtFEBRUr

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean. And where am I missing colons?

Comment: Like change NS line to say: `@    NS    ns1.eg.com.` and `ns1.eg.com.   A    your.dns.servers.ip.address`